# Cannot use constant in object's superclass constructor in Kotlin

Tags: object, kotlin

Doing this works fine:

```kotlin
class DBHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper(GLOBAL_CONTEXT, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
 companion object {
  private const val DATABASE_NAME = "database.db"
  private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
 }
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```kotlin
object DBHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper(GLOBAL_CONTEXT, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
  private const val DATABASE_NAME = "database.db"
  private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
}
```

Why is this the case and how to work around it (other than converting the object to class)?

Comment: Perhaps because the companion object can exist before the class does, but the singleton object's fields are only initialized after the superconstructor is called

Comment: I'd suggest specifying the compilation error you get in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the constants outside the object. They can't be used in its constructor because they are not initialized until the object is.

```
private const val DATABASE_NAME = "database.db"
private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1

object DBHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper(GLOBAL_CONTEXT, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
}
```